# Proper verb form usage after preposition

Tags: grammar, tense

Which of these are correct and what tenses are they in?
I have a feeling that the second one is the correct usage but if both of them are correct, What are the different meanings each have?

> Was it heated before testing?
>
> Was it heated before test?

Also a side question: When I tried these in Grammarly, it suggested adding a **the** to the second sentence(but not the first one). Is this necessary here when the listener knows what test we are talking about? If it is, Why isn't it necessary for the first one?

> Was it heated before **the** test?

Comment: The first sounds good.  The second does not because test becomes a noun here and needs "the".  Gammarly's suggestion is also fine (though it changes the meaning slightly to a single test instead of the act of testing in general), but you can use "the testing" as well.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Isn't "testing" here a noun as well (like how a gerund is a noun)? Why should I add 'the' in the second case but not in the first?

Comment: I have a feeling that testing is a group noun in this case, but I am not a grammar expert to that level, just a native speaker reacting to how it sounds in my head :)